# How to render this with pagination foreign key

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5

How to Render This with Pagination
this is my View

```
@foreach($forumindex->forumindex()->paginate(3) as $comment)
<p><div class="well">{{ $comment->comment }}</div></p>
@endforeach
```

when i try to render like this its not working

```
{!! $forumindex->render() !!}
```

Comment: Can you show me your query?

Comment: It is better if you assign `$forumindex->forumindex()->paginate(3)` to a variable in the controller and then pass it in the view.

Comment: But foreach blade template not gonna work on controller this is relationship data